# java.awt.event cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android

I have the error *java.awt.event cannot be resolved* in the statement:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
```

I'm writing an android application that fires an action (by extending the AbstractAction class) when an SMS is received. I'm implementing the ActionListener interface in another class.

**EDIT**

The above issue is resolved. Now which classes shall I use that'll let me fire actions like in java swing. Or shall I use another way? I basically need to call a method on another thread.

Comment: did u add the package to ur project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm writing an android application

Well that's the problem then... Android doesn't support the whole of the AWT; it has its own GUI libraries. See the [platform reference documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) for details. It's not clear which `AbstractAction` class you're talking about, either - is it a third-party one? If so, look at that third-party documentation to see whether another library is required for AWT-like classes.

Have you looked at whether what you're trying to do might be better achieved using the "normal" Android platform API instead? I'd expect that to be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

```
Java Standard Edition - (AWT + SWING) = Android.
```

The above statement means that **Android doesn't support** `Swing and AWT` from Java SE.
Android provides its own GUI library, i think usage of GUI in android is far more easier to construct.